# How to use a condition in a MutableState in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to change my loginEnabled value to true or false based off two textfield's being not empty, however my current implementation always returns false, can someone see what mistake im making? My email & password state's are updated using the onValueChange function inside two textfield's

```
@Composable
fun LoginScreen() {

var email by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
var password by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
var passwordVisibility by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
var loginEnabled by remember { mutableStateOf(
    email.isNotEmpty() && password.isNotEmpty()
)}

        TextField(
        value = email,
        onValueChange = { email = it },
        label = { Text("Email") }
        )

        TextField(
        value = password,
        onValueChange = { password= it },
        label = { Text("Password") }
        )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@Composable
fun LoginScreen() {

var email by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
var password by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
var passwordVisibility by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
var loginEnabled = email.isNotEmpty() && password.isNotEmpty()

        TextField(
        value = email,
        onValueChange = { email = it },
        label = { Text("Email") }
        )

        TextField(
        value = password,
        onValueChange = { password= it },
        label = { Text("Password") }
        )
```

Your code did not work as expected because you were using a `remember` block, which was preventing re-calculation of the `loginEnabled` variable. Whenever a value on which it depends changed, a recomposition would be triggered, but `remember` would return the previously stored value and prevent it from updating correctly. All that was required was to remove the `remember` from the initialization bit, and the code worked.

As pointed out by @TylerGanon in the comment below, when a single variable depends on multiple other variables, where every variable (including the dependent one) are supposed to be state-holders, i.e., they are of type `MutableState<T>`, it is better to use `derivedStateOf {...}` to get values for the dependent variable. The usage is as

```
@Composable fun CountDisplay(count: State<Int>) {
    Text("Count: ${count.value}")
}

@Composable fun Example() {
    var a by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
    var b by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
    val sum = remember { derivedStateOf { a + b } }
    // Changing either a or b will cause CountDisplay to recompose but not trigger Example
    // to recompose.
    CountDisplay(sum)
}
```

So it is a bit different than `mutableStateOf()` since when a state-holder that it depends on, changes -- it will not cause a recomposition of the entire composable, but only a re-calculation. For example, above, when `a` or `b` changed, the `Example` Composable did NOT recompose, because the only places `a` and `b` were being read in the `Composable` was the `calculation` block of the `derivedStateOf` call. Hence, only a re-calculation took place and updated the value of the dependent variable, i.e., `sum`. Now, since `sum` is again not directly used in `Example`, it will still not recompose, but it is being passed as a parameter to `CountDisplay`, making it the only `Composable` to recompose in this entire process. So, changing the value of `a`, and `b` did not trigger any recompositions on `Example`, but triggered one on `CountDisplay`.

Are we clear?

Comment: You could also ```var loginEnabled by mutableStateOf(email.isNotEmpty() && password.isNotEmpty())```

Comment: If required, although I don't think it will be

Comment: Shouldn't this use use `loginEnabled = derivedStateOf {...}`?  Still learning but I thought this is necessary to ensure updates to all consumers of `loginEnabled` when either `email` or `password` have changed.

Comment: Yes that is why I mentioned the first comment. I thought he might not require recompositions on the value change of login. This was answered almost a year ago when I was dumb, so I didn't even give an explanation of why my solution worked. `derivedStateOf` seems to be a good call in similar scenarios but here the state depends on only two variables, so it's not exactly necessary. Just a simple wrap in a `mutableStateOf()` should do. Both of the individual components being `MutableState<T>` as well,

Comment: @TylerGannon Thank you, please read the updated answer on the thread.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the doc for `remember(calculation: @DisallowComposableCalls () -> T): T`:

> Remember the value produced by [calculation]. [calculation] will only
> be evaluated during the composition.Recomposition will always return the value produced by composition

You have to use:

```
var loginEnabled by remember(email, password) { mutableStateOf(
    email.isNotEmpty() && password.isNotEmpty()
)}
```

> Remember the value returned by calculation if key1 and key2 are equal
> to the previous composition, otherwise produce and remember a new
> value by calling calculation.

Comment: You don't need to add the remeber at all in that place. It is just boilerplate because email and password are already remembered in there own initialisation(s)

Comment: You don't have to use it, right. Just wanted to show the correct usage of `remember`, when the state should get updated on recomposition